# JavaScript to download textfiles instead of opening

Tags: javascript, html, download

I am trying to create virtual links of list of files to be downloaded using javascript. The problem is that it is opening all files in the new tabs instead of downloading directly. I want it to be downloaded rather than open in a new tab.

Any help regarding it will be highly appreciated. So far, I have tried the following code to serve the purpose.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      link.href = links[i];
      link.download = tfiles[i];
      link.target = '_blank';
      link.click();

}
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what are the contents in the links array, are the urls to your files ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the download attribute like this `link.download = tfiles[i];` use `setAttribute('download',"download_filename")`. So the resulting code will look like

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      link.href = links[i];
      link.setAttribute('download',tfiles[i]);
      link.target = '_blank';
      link.click();

}
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Assuming that `tfiles` is an array of the file names of files that you want to download.

Try out this working code in a simple html file for more exercise. The code might not work in stackoverflow run snippet, since this is a sand-boxed env.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    function download() {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.setAttribute('download', "download");
      link.href = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
      link.target = '_blank';
      link.click();
    }
  </script>

  <p>Click on the download button to download the image:
    <p>

      <button onClick="download()"> download</button>

      <p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a Blob for this. You can use fetch to get the blob and then download. Similar to below:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) 
{
    fetch(links[i])
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = url;
            link.download = 'file_' + i;
            link.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
         })
}
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The contents of the text files are dynamic and I do need to download those files only, cant change the contents. In that case, the blob will be useful (just to download files already in the server)?

Comment: You should be able to use fetch to get the file and create a blob